# Why AP_POWER_STATE_REQ is read only in Vehicle HAL

Tags: android, automotive

I see in type.hal , `AP_POWER_STATE_REQ` is read-only.. 
How can `VMCU - Power Controller` can change powerState of Android Automotive OS?
My assumtion is that there will be a native service- a client of VHAL where handle communication with VMCU and then request `AP_POWER_STATE_REQ` .. to enter shutdown, `ON_FULL or DISP_OFF`...
But how can i do that if `AP_POWER_STATE_REQ` is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AP_POWER_STATE_REQ can be set via Vehicle Network Service only not via access Property.
There will be a Chanel provide that possibility.
eg . Service handle CAN message in AP. or UART communication

Answer (score 0):

Check [Power management](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/power/power) for understanding Automotive's power management and required properties to handle the power events.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, as they are rendered useless if the link stops working or the content changes significantly. You should [edit] your answer to include the most important information relevant to the question in the answer itself. Answers that are little more than an external link may end up being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).